# Updating a Databound GridView with changes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview, inotifypropertychanged

I have a DataGridView on a form that is databound to a list of objects.  I have several column including a checkbox column.  The requirement is that only one item in the collection may have the databound boolean property set to true at a given time.  The data object is named Interval, the Property in question is Program:

```
public bool Program
{
    get { return _program; }
    set
    {
        if (value)
        {
            Parent.Intervals.Except(new[] { this }).ForEach(interval => interval.Program = false);
        }
        _program = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }
```

My expected behavior would be that clicking the databound checkbox would set the Program property for one instance of Interval to true, and in so doing, would set the Program property on all other instances to false.  That is indeed what happens, however the datagridview does not update correctly.  It will leave previous checkboxes checked and after tabbing off the cell or mousing over another checkbox, then it will update that particular checkbox.

How can I get the datagrid view to accurately show the state of my objects.  I trusted you, DataGridView!  You lied to me.  I... I can never trust anything you say again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a BindingList instead.  When binding to a regular List or other collection (that is not  of a Binding specific bent), only the selected rows values are updated.  BindingList, however, has the added benefit that properties from all of the items are updated, not just the selected Row.  Keep in mind that if you are using something like AddRange (from List) you may have to modify your code to add items either at initialization time or via a loop, as BindingList does not have an AddRange method (although an extension method could be written).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[CheckBoxColumnIndex].Value)
    {
        var rows = (from DataGridViewRow row in Clients.Rows 
                    where row.Index != e.RowIndex
                    select row).ToArray(); 

        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in rows)
        {
             row.Cells[CheckBoxColumnIndex].Value = false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: That looks like it might work too.  In my case, normally a WPF developer, I am doing my best to keep explicit wrangling of the UI to an absolute minimum.